# Set multiple textbox name with PHP variable dynamically and get value from it?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<?php 
$token2 = stroke($micro, ",");
     while ($token2 !== false)
     {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><strong>$token2</strong> :-</td><td><input type='text' name='$token2' placeholder='Enter tested result value'></td>";
        $token2 = strtok(",");
        echo "</td>";
    }
?>
```

In above code token2 variable has many words (nutrient names) with "," separator and I want each word should accept some integer value, so I created textbox for each to accept value and get it value on another page. All textboxes are dynamically created.[image]

Comment: Simply hit submit button and write `print_r($_POST);`. But make sure you are in form tag and method is POST

Comment: @RobinSingh Thanks. It is working, but how can I get each value separately? I am getting result like "Array ( [OC] => 2 [N] => 2 [Zn] => 2 [Mn] => 2 [submit2] => Submit )". However I have to get each value like OC=2, N=2 etc.

Comment: This is also simple `foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {print_r($value[$key]);}`

Comment: @RobinSingh Getting warning like "Warning: Illegal string offset 'OC' in F:\wamp\www\rkmr\analyst\ressave.php on line 34" for each

Comment: You have to check yourself. This is simple

Comment: @RobinSingh Solved, thanks again.